# File indexing program not working

Tags: java, indexing, bluej, alphabetical

I have to make a program that reads each word a file and makes an index of which lines the word occurs on in alphabetical order.

for example, if the file had:

a white white dog
crowded around the valley

the output should be:

a
around: 2
crowded: 2
dog: 1
the: 2
valley: 1
white: 1, 1

---

When my file contains:

one fish two fish blue fish green fish
cow fish milk fish dog fish red fish
can you find a little lamb
can you find a white calf

THE OUTPUT IS WRONG!: (NOT IN ALPHA ORDER)

a: 3 4
calf: 4
find: 3 4 4
lamb: 3
little: 3
white: 4
you: 3 4
blue: 1
can: 3
cow: 2
dog: 2
green: 1 1 2 2 2 2
milk: 2
red: 2
two: 1 1 1
fish: 1
one: 1

---

Here is my code::

INDEXMAKER MASTER CLASS

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class IndexMaker {
    private ArrayList<Word> words;
    private String fileName;
    private String writeFileName;

    public IndexMaker(String fileName, String writeFileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.writeFileName = writeFileName;
        words = new ArrayList<Word>();
    }

    public void makeIndex() {
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(file);
            int lineNum = 0;
            while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
                lineNum++;
                Scanner wordScanner = new Scanner(lineScanner.nextLine());
                while (wordScanner.hasNext()) {
                    String word = wordScanner.next().toLowerCase();
                    if (!words.contains(new Word(word))) {
                        insertInto(word, findPosition(word), lineNum);
                    } else {
                        addLineNum(word, lineNum);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void displayIndex() {
        try {
            //FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(writeFileName));
            //BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            for (Word word : words)
                System.out.println(word.getWord() + ": " + word.getLineNums());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private int findPosition(String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            if (word.compareTo(words.get(i).getWord()) <= 0)
                return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private void insertInto(String word, int pos, int lineNum) {
        words.add(pos, new Word(word, String.valueOf(lineNum)));
    }

    private void addLineNum(String word, int lineNum) {
        int pos = findPosition(word);
        words.get(pos).addLineNum(lineNum);
    }
}
```

WORD CLASS

```
public class Word {
    private String word;
    private String lineNums;
    public Word(String word, String lineNum) {
        this.word = word;
        this.lineNums = lineNum;
    }
    public Word(String word) {
        this.word = word;
        this.lineNums = "";
    }
    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    public String getLineNums() {
        return lineNums;
    }
    public void addLineNum(int num) {
        lineNums += " " + num;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object w) {
        if (((Word)w).getWord().equals(word))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

CLIENT

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IndexMaker indexMaker = new IndexMaker("readme.txt", "readme.txt");
        indexMaker.makeIndex();
        indexMaker.displayIndex();
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find your definition of compareTo.  It seems this would be the key part of your program?

Properly implement your compareTo and confirm it works properly by printing the results of comparisons using System.out.println

Doing your own comparison is "ok" in that it will work if you do it properly.  The other thing you could do would be to implement Comparable and then you can get Java to sort a list of words for you.

Comment: the compareTo just compares the strings it doesnt need to be made

Comment: Maybe I completely misunderstood your question, but it looks like you are saying the problem is that the output is not in alpha order.

Comment: that is the main problem

Comment: What am I misunderstanding then?  Your main problem is that the words are out of order, but you don't want to show us how you designed the method that determines the correct order?